# Grep keyword in multiple files and sort results by files modified date or name

Tags: bash, grep, ag

Trying to search a key word in multiple files. but search results are not sorted by files modified date or name

**ag grep tool:**

```
ag "keyword"
```

**grep tool:**

```
grep -r "keyword"
```

**is there any way we can control the results sort by files modified date or name like following?**

**Expected Output:**

File_0.txt: search results

File_1.txt: search results

File_2.txt: search results

Comment: Try: `grep -r "keyword" | sort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort with `ls` and pass the results into `grep` or `ag`, e.g. to sort by date:

`grep "keyword" $(ls -1rt)`

To sort by name, agin use `ls`. A caveat worth mentioning for the MacOS:  you'll need to use GNU's `ls` (brew install coreutils) with its -U flag:

`ag "keyword" $(gls -U --color)`  #sort by name on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, the following is an option for getting `grep` results sorted by modification date:

```bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    grep -H "keyword" "$file"
done < <(find * -type f -printf "%T@\t%p\0" | sort -rz | cut -z -f2-)
```

A breakdown of the `find` expression:

```bash
find * -type f -printf "%T@\t%p\0" |    # print last-mod date and filename, NUL-terminated
    sort -rz |                          # sort in reverse order
    cut -z -f2-                         # cut out time field
```